# SQLDateTime OverFlow with Correct DateTime Format

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime

below is my code snippet where I insert a DateTime value to SQL database and encountered the following error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be
>   between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

```
deliveryCart.DeliveryDate = (DateTime)row.DeliveryDate;

Log.SaveLog(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"] + @"\Log.txt", "deliveryCart.DeliveryDate: " + deliveryCart.DeliveryDate.ToString());
//*value retrieved is 12/31/2019 12:00:00 AM

dataContext.Q_TBL_SUBMITTED_DELIVERY_CARTs.InsertOnSubmit(deliveryCart);
```

May I know if there is a format to be used? when converting the value of `row.DeliveryDate`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error - SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468045/error-sqldatetime-overflow-must-be-between-1-1-1753-120000-am-and-12-31-999)

Comment: Does that deliveryCart have any other dates, that may be at DateTime.MinValue? What are the properties of deliveryCart and what are the columns (and their types) of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the problem is  `SQL DateTime` =/=  `C# Datetime`

you need to change 2 things

- Database change the field type from `DateTime` to `DateTime2`
- Query you need to be explicit

you can find futher informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1334193/1993545),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12364243/1993545) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566210/sqldatetime-overflow-exception-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dateTime.toString(), then need to ensure that the string is formatted per:

```
deliveryCart.DeliveryDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff");
```

Also, DateTime is a value type and not a reference type. So, it cant be null. Value types if not initialised have a value of 0. For Datetime, it can be DateTime.MinValue which is outside Sql Server's value.

Comment: You shouldn't pass that date value as *string* to SQL, but as (the DateTime value of) a parameter of some date type. So no formatting needed.